# sql request with access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, request

I have two tables.

- CENTER defines by an ID and a Name
- BUILDINGS defines by ID, PK_CENTER, NbPlace, Type

I want the name of the centers which have buildings with:

```
TYPE equals "flat" and NbPlace => 6
```

and

```
TYPE equals "Room" and NbPlace => 6.
```

I'm stuck, I don't know how to get the centers.

Tks

Comment: so buildings contains multiple records for center each type? or nbplace?

Comment: One CENTER contains MULTIPLE BUILDINGS.
BUILDINGS have a number of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of query can be answered using aggregation and a `having` clause.  To get the centers:

```
select pk_center
from buildings
group by pk_center
having sum(iif(TYPE = "flat" and NbPlace >= 6, 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(TYPE = "Room" and NbPlace >= 6, 1, 0)) > 0;
```

Each expression in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows that match one of the conditions.  The `> 0` is saying that there is at least one match.

Note:  I don't recognize `=>`.  I assume you mean `>=`.

EDIT:

With the `join` to get the center name:

select c.id, c.name
from centers as c inner join
     buildings as b
     on c.id =, c.pk_center
group by c.id, c.name
having sum(iif(TYPE = "flat" and NbPlace >= 6, 1, 0)) > 0 and
       sum(iif(TYPE = "Room" and NbPlace >= 6, 1, 0)) > 0;

Comment: Yes, tks, my bad, I mean `>=.

Comment: But I need to display the name of each Center, so I need to do a select on the CENTER table no ? (not on the building table)

Comment: @Raphael . . . that is accomplished with a simple `join`.  It wasn't clear in your question.